# update mysql table records automatically every first of year using laravel 4.2

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, auto-update

I have users table have column named balance I want to auto update balance column  for all users First every year + value (30) as every user will gain 30 points credit yearly on first of year how can i make this query and make it auto run First every year

sample for my table

**id   name   balance**

1      name1    20

2      name2    31

2      name3    14

Comment: I would use a command http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/commands and schedule this with the cron manager of your server.

Comment: can you add more details for how to make it please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by using c-panel [Cron Jobs](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Cron+Jobs) I created php script for connecting to database and update the records then i put this script path in Cron Jobs command like this

```
php -f /script-path/scriptName.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I would leave laravel completely out of the picture. Use either mysql's built-in [event scheduler](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/working-mysql-scheduled-event/) or use your OS' similar functionality (e.g. cron or windows task scheduler) to schedule the run of bit of sql script. If you use OS event scheduler, then use mysql's [command line client](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql.html) to execute the sql script.

Depending on your business requirements, probably you want to run the script every day to update those balances that were registered 1 year agao.

Your sql will be sg like the below one:

```
update table set balance=balance+30 where field_for_creation_date=curdate() - interval 1 year
```

I assume that you store the date of registration / activation from which the 1 year is calculated in a field, I named it field_for_creation_date in the above query.

Comment: I use c-panel on centos OS how can i make it on this environment and how to test it on local host? also i want to know if any way to make it on my code

Comment: How to manage cron jobs in cpanel: https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Cron+Jobs

Comment: How to configure a cron job in cpanel: https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/ALD/Configure+cPanel+Cron+Jobs

Comment: You can do it from php code as well (but bit of an overkill, esspeciallzywith laravel) bzyscheduling the run of the php file with cron an issuing the sql command from there.

Comment: i never used laravel cron before can you tell me where i found cron file on my project and where to put my query? and can i use elequant  query? like " $user->update(['balance', $user->balance + 30]);"

Comment: 1. No, I cannot tell you, where you can find your cron file on your server. I do not have access to it. A google serach will help you to find it on you OS (if it is installed) 2. Yes, you can use eloquent query to run the update. But I would not use it, it is just waste of time and resources in this particular case.

Comment: I don't have rights to access my server cron any way else to put this query on my project php files to run and check if the current date is the first year then make update?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95239/discussion-between-maged-hamid-and-shadow).

Comment: Check mysql event scheduler as well.